# matplotlib showing strange diagrams

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to get a plot to show the avg temperature throughout the year.  I need my x axis to be May through April.  I am able to get everything to show up but it keeps putting the temperature in its own little block then putting all the months off to the side any help would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from random import*
avg, sTemp = ([] for i in range(2))
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
i, avgsum, beg, end = 0, 0, 0, 18
sDate = ["May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", "January", "Febuary", "March", "April"]
df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\shilo\Documents\pd.xlsx')
date = df['D'].tolist()
low = df['L'].tolist()
high = df['H'].tolist()
for x, c in zip(low,high):
   if (x=='M'):
       low [i] = low [i-1]
   if (c =='M'):
       high [i] = high[i-1]
   avg.append((low[i]+high[i])/2)
   i+=1
sampMean = np.mean(avg)
sampVar = np.var(avg)
for x in range(20):
   i = randrange(beg,end)
   sTemp.append(avg[i])
   if (x%3 ==0):
       beg+=19
       end+=19
   else:
       beg+=18
       end+=18
sVar = np.var(sTemp)
sM = np.mean(sTemp)
p=plt.hist(sTemp, bins = 10, density = True)
plt.show()
plt.plot(sTemp)
plt.ylabel("Temp in Farenheit")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.xticks(sTemp,sDate)
plt.show()
```

additionally here is what it puts out

[image]

Also, I'm sure by reading the code you see there is another graph that is supposed to pop up and it does but that one is fine so I didn't include it.  If it helps though let me know and I'll post it.

upcoming graph is for `plt.plot(sDate, sTemp)`

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to create the plots next to each other? Then I would suggest you should try using subplots.

Comment: @ashishv I am trying to get the bottom to read the months and the line plot to go from beginning to end of the plot .  Basically I'm trying to change the ticks to be months instead of numbers

Comment: I think firstly that you plt.plot() is missing the xaxis list for date.

Comment: when I do that though then graph comes out like this ... well it won't let mu upload it to a comment so I'll upload it to the original post

Comment: Please, could you provide a small sample of your data in the `'C:\Users\shilo\Documents\pd.xlsx'` file?

Comment: sure.. I will try and upload it... Trying to upload it the image was too big so I'll just copy a few cells into this comment

5/1/2019 35.1 55.9
5/2/2019 33.1 64
5/3/2019 37.9 71.1
5/4/2019 42.1 75.9
5/5/2019 46 77
5/6/2019 44.1 75.9
5/7/2019 46 64.9
5/8/2019 44.1 64.9
5/9/2019 42.1 62.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** The first argument in `plt.plot(x, y)` i.e. `x` should  have distinct values. This weird diagram was the result of having non-distinct values in `x`.

`plt.xticks(sTemp, sDate)` should be `plt.xticks(sDate)`. But, I'm not sure if you'd need to use `plt.xticks` as you are using `plt.xlabel`.

The `figsize` should have a larger width so that the month names don't overlap.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from random import*

# str_t is the data provided by op
str_t = r'''5/1/2019 35.1 55.9
5/2/2019 33.1 64
5/3/2019 37.9 71.1
5/4/2019 42.1 75.9
5/5/2019 46 77
5/6/2019 44.1 75.9
5/7/2019 46 64.9
5/8/2019 44.1 64.9
5/9/2019 42.1 62.1'''

date = []
low = []
high = []
for el in str_t.split('\n'):
    val = el.split(' ')
    date.append(val[0])
    low.append(float(val[1]))
    high.append(float(val[2]))
# print(str_t)

avg, sTemp = ([] for i in range(2))
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
i, avgsum, beg, end = 0, 0, 0, 9
sDate = ["May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", "January", "Febuary", "March", "April"]


for x, c in zip(low,high):
   if (x=='M'):
       low [i] = low [i-1]
   if (c =='M'):
       high [i] = high[i-1]
   avg.append((low[i]+high[i])/2)
   i+=1
sampMean = np.mean(avg)
sampVar = np.var(avg)
for x in range(12):
   i = randrange(beg,end)
   sTemp.append(avg[i])
   # commented as the data has only 12 rows,
   # thus +19 exceeds the array/list index
   # if (x%3 ==0):
   #     beg+=19
   #     end+=19
   # else:
   #     beg+=18
   #     end+=18
sVar = np.var(sTemp)
sM = np.mean(sTemp)
# p=plt.hist(sTemp, bins = 10, density = True)
# plt.show()

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12, 5))
axs.plot(sDate, sTemp)
axs.set_ylabel("Temp in Farenheit")
axs.set_xlabel("Date")
plt.show()
```

**Output:**
[image]

You may use the following code to plot 2 diagrams.

```py
from matplotlib import gridspec
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,5))
spec = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=2, nrows=1,
                         width_ratios=[1, 2])

ax0 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0])
ax0.hist(sTemp, bins = 10, density = True)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(spec[1])
ax1.plot(sDate, sTemp)
ax1.set_ylabel("Temp in Farenheit")
ax1.set_xlabel("Date")
plt.show()
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: So I've been working on it using your example and the may - april diagram is still coming out weird. (Like in the second plot diagram).   FYI  I don't know if this is important or not but I'm importing the data from an excel file and there are 365 points of data, one for each day.  Some points are labeled 'M' for missing etc.  I don't know if that is helpful

Comment: What is the `length` or `shape` of `sTemp` and `sDate` in your code?

Comment: I have 20 points of data for sTemp, so I've added a few blank spaces into sDate to get that up to 20 points of data as well

Comment: I think labels should be distinct. Rather than using four blank spaces, use `1,2,3,4 etc` and see if it fixes your issue.